# When pasting into the console, spaces after command are causing issue

Tags: r

I have a simple line of code, with multiple readline commands that works just fine if I type it into the console directly, or paste it in from an existing R document without any excess spaces after the last bracket.

```
{ v1 <- readline("Choose 1: "); v2 <- readline("Choose 2: "); v3<- readline("Choose 2: ")}
```

If I run the above line I will be asked to Choose 1, then Choose 2, then Choose 3. This example is simple, but it is how I like to enter a lot of my data.

But if I inadvertently copy some empty spacing after the line of code when copying from an R document, or the above line is included with other code like so:

```
X<-c(1,2,3,4,5)

{ v1 <- readline("Choose 1: "); v2 <- readline("Choose 2: "); v3<- readline("Choose 2: ")}

Y<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

All three readline commands will be printed at once, so that I can't enter my data in.

I've tried including the readline statements in a function, but I run into the same kind of problem with pasting spaces after the function call, causing the readline statements to all be printed out at once.

```
fun<-function(){
v1 <- readline("Choose 1: "); v2 <- readline("Choose 2: "); v3<- readline("Choose 2: ")
}

fun()

Y<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

The only luck I've had is to use source() to call a function from a separate R document, but I'm trying to avoid using source and keep everything in one R document. Ideally I'd like to be able to run multiple readline (or some other way to be asked to enter data), from a piece of code sandwiched in other code.

Comment: Is this in the standard R GUI?

Comment: I am using the standard R console running version 3.0.1 on a mac

Comment: Seems like there is a [relevant thread here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Wait-for-user-input-with-readline-td3054517.html). Looks like the problem is that R doesn't have a good "copy/paste" mode. It either is running in interactive mode where it assumes you're typing each line, or it runs in non-interactive mode and won't wait for input. So when you're copying and pasting, you're really just typing very fast. R can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention your operating system but on Windows and maybe others this works:

```
source("clipboard")
```